# fetch json file into angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

i'm trying to fetch a json file on my local server in which i have stored few arrays. I'm trying to achieve this by using the $http service for which the code runs as below:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('store', ['store-products']);
    app.controller('StoreController',['$http', function($http){
        var store = this;
        store.products = [];
        $http.get('products.json').success(function(data){
            store.products = data;
        })
})();
```

And my products.json file:

```
[ {
    "name" : "Lasagna",
    "price" : 250,
    "images":[{"full":"images/lasagne.jpg"}],
    "Description":"Lasagne are wide, flat-shaped pasta, and possibly one of the oldest types of pasta.The word 'lasagne', and, in many non-Italian languages, the singular 'lasagna', can also refer to a dish made with several layers of lasagne sheets alternated with sauces and various other ingredients.",
    "canPurchase": true,
    "Reviews":[]

            },
            {
    "name":"Shawarma",
    "price":300,
    "images":[{"full":"images/shawarma.jpg"}],
    "Description":"Shawarma or Shawurma  is a Levantine meat preparation, where lamb, chicken, turkey, beef, veal, buffalo meat, or mixed meats are placed on a spit (commonly a vertical spit in restaurants), and may be grilled for as long as a day.Shavings are cut off the block of meat for serving, and the remainder of the block of meat is kept heated on the rotating spit. Shawarma can be served on a plate (generally with accompaniments), or as a sandwich or wrap. Shawarma is usually eaten with tabbouleh, fattoush, taboon bread, tomato, and cucumber. Toppings include tahini, hummus, pickled turnips, and amba",
    "canPurchase": true,
    "Reviews":[]
    }]
```

And my html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="store">
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <h1 align="center"><ul>Food Junkie</ul></h1>
    <h2 align="center">-It's all gonna be alright-</h2> 
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat ="product in store.products">
            <product-title></product-title>
            <product-images></product-images>
            <button ng-show="product.canPurchase"><img src="images/cart_64x64.jpg"/></button></br>
            <product-panel></product-panel>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ang.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you get as a result when you directly request the `<server_url>/product.json` from a web browser or a rest client?

Comment: @AsielLealCeldeiro: I get the array which i have listed.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like that, but your url is wrong. If the json file is in the root just use `$http.get('product.json')`, otherwise don't start with a dash `/`, I.e: `$http.get('path/to/product.json')`

Be aware of your Angular version too since the latest version replaced the `$http` `.success()` and `.error()` for `.then()` and `.catch()`

Comment: Yeah i tried removing the back-slash but nothing's changed and the minified version of angularjs i'm using is stored in my local server(not a CDN) and i'm sure it's not the updated version.

Comment: What error are you getting? 404? If you are serving the json, have you tried with an absolute path instead of relative?

Comment: Yes , i'm getting  the array listed when i give the path to .json file but the path that i've mentioned in my js file is just the file name cause it's in my root folder.

Comment: You should be using absolute path or defining the root with: <base href="/application_root/" />

Comment: i changed the path to "http://localhost/project_2/products.json" but nothing changed